# Agregar datos a DataGridView sin eliminar datos contenidos

Tags: sql, windows-forms, formularios

Estoy realizando un punto de venta utilizando Windows Forms pero me surgió un problema. Cuando leo el código de barras de un producto, se conecta a la base de datos y se anexa el producto en el `DataGridView` correctamente, pero cuando leo otro producto se elimina el que ya tenia y se agrega el nuevo.

El código es el siguiente:

```
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto='" + txtCodigoBarras.Text + "'", cn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;   
    }
```

Lo que necesito es que al seguir leyendo codigos de barras, se sigan añadiendo al DataGridView, y que no se eliminen.

Desde ya, gracias.

SOLUCION: La solucion que se le dio fue la siguiente.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    private void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM productos WHERE id_producto='" + txtCodigoBarras.Text + "'", cn);
        MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        da.Fill(dt);
        dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

   }
```

Comment: En tu código, cada vez que se ejecuta el DataTable dt=new DataTable(); crea uno nuevo, y por lo tanto borra lo que tenía antes. Busca cómo declararlo fuera del evento del botón y sólo agrega la información al datatable ya creado...

Comment: Perfecto, esto funciono de maravilla. Gracias por la ayuda. Adjunto como quedaría el codigo.